# SQL Server - Date String

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Can you please help me create an sql statement that will get the previous date and concatenate that date in this format:

```
'2016-05-05 00:00:00'
```

I already know the sql function to get the previous date but I don't know yet on how to get the time in the expected format. My query is something like this

```
Select * 
from table 
where 
    transaction_date between '2016-05-05 00:00:00' and '2016-05-05 23:59:59'
```

So I need `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` to be concatenated in the date.

Comment: If I understand the question, you want to get rows from table where `transaction_date` is within the given date?

Comment: select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you mark one of these answers as the correct one, to reward the answerer for their efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the times at all. Just don't use `BETWEEN` and use `>=` and `<` for the next day, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE transaction_date >= '2016-05-05'
AND transaction_date < '2016-05-06'
```

Or if you only have the single date value:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2016-05-05'

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE transaction_date >= @date
AND transaction_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date)
```

The added benefit of doing it this way is that you also don't miss out on times that occur in the last second of the day as your original query does. For example `2016-05-05 23:59:59.001`

#### Edit: From the comments below

To get yesterdays date, get today's date and subtract a day from it:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Now use the logic as mentioned above.

Comment: thank you to all of those who responded. I think I have not been more specific with my question. I want to get the yesterday date and put that in my selection criteria.  So my query is something like this:  Select * from table where transaction_date = yesterday date. Initially I used the statement SELECT * from table where transaction_date = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) and the date result was: 2016-05-05 00:00:00.000 thus my query did not generate any data.

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

...will turn `2016-05-05 18:18:231` into `2016-05-05 00:00:000`. From there it is easy to get full date boundaries by adding and subtracting days:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
        ,@YesterdayStartDate DATETIME
        ,@TodayStartDate DATETIME

SET @Date = GetDate()
SET @TodayStartDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)
SET @YesterdayStartDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, @TodayStartDate)

SELECT @Date, @YesterdayStartDate, @TodayStartDate

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
    transaction_date >= @YesterdayStartDate AND 
    transaction_date < @TodayStartDate
```

Comment: Thank you guys especially to Malk...I got the data now :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result with transaction_date on yesterday.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE   
    transaction_date BETWEEN dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0) AND dateadd(DAY, 1, dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare date with out time part . ie below code.

```
Select * from table 
 where  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), transaction_date , 112) =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),   getdate(), 112)
```

Comment: Hi All,  I also need help on how can I subtract one day from a DD/MM/YYYY format from a flat file. Sample data is 30/06/2015 and I want to subtract one day from it.